# How to rectify CSS styling in Angular after injecting Selector in your HTML?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to break repeating code into components just to make the code clean. But when I converted a chunk of code into a component and use its selector in the code, the styling breaks.

So basically, this is what I'm getting right now:

[image: What is]
And this is what I'm trying to get:

[image: What should]

As you can see, the main content shifts downward. Even though, I placed the selector exactly where the code was present before. How do I prevent this from happening?

StackBlitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mk3swj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```html
   <div class="feature style">
     <div class="row">
       <app-nav-menu class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></app-nav-menu>
       <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
         <div class="row rs-counter resource">
             ...
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Although, the content did shift to the left. The navigation on the right shrinks and takes a blocky shape instead of a rectangular one in the screenshot.

Comment: you can use `col-md-4` on `app-nav-menu` and `col-md-8` on `div`. Try adjusting these.

Comment: I found the solution. I removed to the class `class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 d-md-block sidebar"` from `nav` tag. And applied it to the custom selector `<app-nav-menu>`.

Comment: Ya, but i didn't see any `sidebar` css class in the code. And I think.
It is better to keep it like this  `class="col-md-3 col-lg-3`. you can avoid unnecessary code.